# AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call logs:DescribeLogGroups in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am getting

> AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call logs:DescribeLogGroups

[image]

What does it actually mean? My current user is an admin with AdministratorAccess.

Comment: Can you share more details about this issue? Also, the event stacktrace from cloudformation, please.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. The real question is: _what user was in effect when it happened_? Are you running your CloudFormation templates with a role? Are you calling out to Lambda functions, and if so what is their role? Do you in fact know that your console user has this permission (yes, I know you _think_ you know, but do you really know? can you go to the CloudWatch Logs page in the console and see log groups?)

Comment: Need more details..How you are creating your stack. by running from another aws service?